# How to use perl script filter xml tags when there has some same tag names?

Tags: xml, perl

I'm using command line doing filtering, below are my XML file

```
<data>
    <numbers>
        <value>1</value>
        <extra>
            <value>a</value>
        </extra>
    </numbers>
    <numbers>
        <value>2</value>
        <extra>
            <value>b</value>
        </extra>
    </numbers>
    <numbers>
        <value>3</value>
    </numbers>
    <numbers>
        <value>10</value>
        <extra>
            <value>c</value>
        </extra>
    </numbers>
    <numbers>...</numbers>
    ...
</data>
```

As you see, I want the values in the "value" tag that under "numbers", but when I use my perl code to filter it, the "value" under "extra" tags will also appear, how should I do to just keep the "value" tag that under "numbers" and remove the "value" tags that under "extra"???

below is my perl code:(command line format)

```
perl -nle 'while(<stdin>){if(/data|numbers|value/){chop; print}}' < sample.xml > output.xml
```

the output of this command line is:

```
<data>
    <numbers>
        <value>1</value>
            <value>a</value>
    </numbers>
    <numbers>
        <value>2</value>
            <value>b</value>
    </numbers>
    <numbers>
        <value>3</value>
    </numbers>
    <numbers>
        <value>10</value>
            <value>c</value>
    </numbers>
    <numbers>...</numbers>
    ...
</data>
```

Yes, the "extra" tags are removed, but the "value" tags in the "extra" tags are still there, I don't want them, please help me edit my command-line code, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 4):

There's no point in spending a lot of time and effort writing your own XML parser when great ones already exist.

---

**Blacklist approach**

To delete `extra` elements:

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file('sample.xml');

for my $node ($doc->findnodes('/data/numbers/extra')) {
   $node->unbindNode();
}

$doc->toFile('output.xml');
```

---

**Whitelist approach**

To remove all the elements except those you said you wanted to keep:

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );

sub qualified_name {
   my ($node) = @_;
   if (defined($node->namespaceURI())) {
      return sprintf("{%s}%s", $node->namespaceURI(), $node->nodeName());
   } else  {
      return $node->nodeName();
   }
}

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file('sample.xml');

for my $node ($doc->findnodes('/data/*')) {
   if (qualified_name($node) ne "numbers") {
      $node->unbindNode();
      next;
   }

   for my $node ($node->findnodes('*')) {
      if (qualified_name($node) ne "value") {
         $node->unbindNode();
         next;
      }
   }
}

$doc->toFile('output.xml');
```